# acer aspire one d270: Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, acer, aspire

I've bought an Acer Aspire One D270 netbook as a Cristmass Gift for my wife. Now I'm not sure which version of Ubuntu will work best: the new 12.10 or the LTS 12.04?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Strong Recommendation:***

First install **12.04 LTS** ..

This will be good for the next 2-3 years, without any issues.

---

If you also want to *try* 12.10, and 13.04 (in a few months), and then 13.10 (later next year) you can.

But, if your target audience (*your wife*) just wants to use a computer, they may not want you mucking with it every six months.

You could also try (and not initially install) 12.10 (and 13.04), to see if there are any new *must have* features. Examples in future may include major 'improvements' to the user interface, better multi-touch support, etc.

*If might be better to have a second netbook for **you** to 'play' on ..*

Comment: Well, in fact, I was trying to install allmost all current flavors of Ubuntu / Ubuntu like (Mint). and the only one, that works _allmost_ without problems was 12.04